# How to adjust variable to sync events from one calendar to a group calendar

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create/modify a script where a team member can add an event in their calendar under a certain keyword. I used this script because I also needed the group calendar I'm using the script on to have vacation and OOO time auto-populated. This works fine, but my additional keywords aren't working.

I'm using the script in this link for reference: https://developers.google.com/gsuite/solutions/vacation-calendar

I've added my google group email, calendar ID, and I've added additional keywords outside of what's already set up.

I've modified my sync timeframe from 1hr to minutes.

OOO, Out of Office keywords work perfectly, but not the ones I've added.

Here's the script after the group email and calendar ID request - these two work fine, so there's not an issue with that piece of code... modified based on what I need (keywords).

Using that reference script, I've only modified the keywords section:

**var KEYWORDS = ['vacation', 'ooo', 'out of office', 'offline', 'FV2'];**

I expect that a user under this group email will be able to create a calendar event using any of the keywords above and that it will automatically populate onto the group calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script contains the lines

```
  if (event.summary.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) < 0) {
    return false;
  }
```

This means that it sets the events retrieved from the user's calendar to lowercase and compares them against the keywords.

### If your keyword is in uppercase - the script will not find the event within the keyword array.

**Modification point:**

Use only lowercase keywords, e.g.

`var KEYWORDS = ['vacation', 'ooo', 'out of office', 'offline', 'fv2'];`

Comment: This modification worked. Thank you for the advice!